# Tokenize the string based on commaspacealphabet using xslt regex pattern

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to tokenize strings inside the content element based on "commaspacealphabet".

```
<content>ss 2(2)(b), 3, Sch 2 line 10, 20,30, paras 10 div 10, 2 , 3</content>
```

Below I mentioned expected output.

```
<content><sub>ss 2(2)(b), 3</sub><sub>Sch 2 line 10, 20,30</sub><sub>paras 10 div 10, 2 , 3</sub></content>
```

Please any one try to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to use analyse-substring with a regex of `,\s+([A-Za-z])` to match the separator, but then output the separator with the captured match written twice.

You can then use `tokenize` the result, using the same regex, to split up the expression, thus removing the duplicate letter, and putting it back as it was, but with `sub` tags around it.

Try this template

```
  <xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:variable name="first">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=",\s+([A-Za-z])">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" />
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($first, ',\s+[A-Za-z]')">
          <sub><xsl:value-of select="." /></sub>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

When applied to this element...

```
<content>ss 2(2)(b), 3, Sch 2 line 10, 20,30, paras 10 div 10, 2 , 3</content>
```

The following is output

```
<content><sub>ss 2(2)(b), 3</sub><sub>Sch 2 line 10, 20,30</sub><sub>paras 10 div 10, 2 , 3</sub></content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would I be right in thinking that you want a comma to act as a separator if and only if the next non-space character is alphabetic? (If so, why didn't you make life easier by saying so?)

And are you using XSLT 2.0? Again, tag your question.

It's tricky to achieve using tokenize() because there is no non-capturing lookahead construct in XPath 2.0 regular expressions.

So I might try:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=",\s*\P{L}">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <sep><xsl:value-of select="."/></sep>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <sub><xsl:value-of select="."/></sub>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

followed by a second pass that merges a `<sub>` element with the first character of the following `<sep>` element.

But perhaps there's a better way, this is a quick first attempt.

Comment: Thanks. But the string may varies. either it starts with any alphabet.

Comment: You're going to have to produce a more detailed specification if you want me to spend any more time on this. As I said, I was guessing what you wanted and your comment doesn't make it any clearer.